# How to randomly group elements of two lists and make new list of the tuples of randomly gotten new elements?

Tags: random, ocaml, shuffle

If I have 2 lists ['a'; 'b'] and [1;2;3;4] I want to get something like [('a',2);('a',4);('b',3); ('b', 1)]. So the point is that I need to use all elements of second list once and I can use elements from the first one 0 or more times... I tried with List.combine but is always connects nth element of 1st list with nth element of the 2nd and list need to have same length as well...

Comment: Your title says you want a random selection from the first list. It's pretty clear that `List.combine` won't be immediately useful since it doesn't have any randomness in its behavior. You might write a function `draw n l` that returns a list of  n random draws (with replacement) from a list l. Then you can use `List.combine` to combine the random draws with the second list. However it's inefficient to draw randomly from a long list. It might be better to start by converting the first list to an array.

Comment: Yes I think the easier way to do this is to convert the lists into arrays and picking random elements with `Random.int`

Answer (score 0):

Use two mappings (`Map.Make(Int).t`) for the first set and the second set. Then populate the first mapping (representing the small group) from the list using the element position as the key. Populate the second mapping from the larger list using a random key, generated with `Random.bits ()`. In case of the collision, i.e., when a generated key is already in the mapping, generate a new key until a fresh key is generated.

To generate the output list, fold over the second mapping, and use `Random.int n` to select the element from the first mapping, where `n` is the size of the first mapping (`Map.cardinal`).

If you are keen to use `Base` then you can think about using `Array.shuffle` to permute lists.